# How to invoke the Add Accessory page of Home app in our own iOS app?

Tags: ios

I have looked into this issue for hours, and have not found the answer.
I want to show the "Add Accessory" page from the Home app directly in my own app, without searching as below functions.

```
    [HMAccessoryBrowser startSearchingForNewAccessories]
    [HMHome addAccessory: completionHandler]
```

See the screenshot below:
[image]